# JSON Parser for Scala 2.12

Tags: json, scala, databricks, jsonparser

I am looking for a way to re-write the following code using a JSON parser. This is currently using `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject` which has been deprecated.

```
   val notebookInfo = Map("notebookURL" -> notebookURL,  
                "user" -> user, 
                "name" -> name,
                "mounts" -> dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt").map(_.path),
                "timestamp" -> System.currentTimeMillis)
  val notebookInfoJson = scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject(notebookInfo)
```

I have tried the following with Circe JSON parser but getting errors:

```
      val notebookInfo = Json.obj("notebookURL" -> Json.fromString(notebookURL),  
                "user" -> Json.fromString(user), 
                "name" -> Json.fromString(name),
                "mounts" -> Json.arr(Seq(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt").map(Json.fromString) :_*),
                "timestamp" -> Json.fromLong(System.currentTimeMillis)))
  val notebookInfoJson = notebookInfo
```

Here are the errors I am seeing:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : String => io.circe.Json
 required: com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FileInfo => ?
                "mounts" -> Json.arr(Seq(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt").map(Json.fromString) :_*),
                                                                        ^
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, io.circe.Json)
 required: io.circe.Json
                "timestamp" -> Json.fromLong(System.currentTimeMillis)))
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear, you say you want to parse the following code using a **Json** parser library? You can not parse **Scala** code using a **Json** library, so I guess it is just an error in the question or I am reading it wrong. - Maybe what you want is to produce a **Json** string from some data?

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez Thanks, I edited the post. Just trying to re-write the code since scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but I do not know what `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject` does, so that is why I ask what is your end goal.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez  It Constructs a JSONObject from in this case, a Map.

Comment: Yeah, but for what do you need that `JSONObject`? - First, you need to understand there is no single and universal `JSONObject` class, so the `JSONObject` you construct with **circe** is a different type that the one constructed with the **scala-util-parsing-json**, so if you need that exact type you can not use **circe** _(nor any other library)_. Now, i doubt you need that exact type, you probably need that `JSONObject` for something else, like printing it as a properly formatted JSON string, or something else. Without those details is hard to help you.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez yes that's right, I'm try to use circe or any other recommended package that will allow me to print it as a properly formatted JSON string.

Comment: You would need to adapt this code a bit but it should work: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/rpI4Ww2kTeWx7xvwzICbbQ/1 in the `BuildSettings` tab you can see how to include **circe**.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez Thanks. I am seeing the following error when I run this in Databricks with Scala 2.12 along with the following circe maven library coordinates: io.circe:circe-parser_2.12:0.14.0-M6. Here is the error: command-1386268496170881:1: error: object generic is not a member of package io.circe
import io.circe.generic.auto._
                ^
command-1386268496170881:20: error: could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[NotebookInfo]
println(notebookInfo.asJson.spaces2)

Comment: First, I would use the stable version `0.13.0` second the `generic` package is part of the **circe-generic** module, you need both the **circe-core** and **circe-generic** _(or just generic which will pull out core for you, but that is usually considered a bad pratice)_; you do not need **circe-parser** unless you also want to parse JSONs.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez Thanks. I have imported the right packages and now seeing this new error: java.io.IOException: Scala signature scalaVersionSpecific has wrong version
 expected: 5.0
 found: 5.2 in scalaVersionSpecific.class

Comment: It seems you included a library with a different **Scala** version of your runtime, make sure your runtime is `2.12` and all your libraries are `2.12` or if your runtime is `2.11` then ensure all your libraries are `2.11` too.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this article](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-json-strings-from-scala-objects/). It has few examples with JSON parsing frameworks that could be used with Scala.

> ```
> import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST
> import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
> import net.liftweb.json.Printer.{compact,pretty}
>
> object LiftJsonWithCollections extends App {
>
>     val json = List(1, 2, 3)
>     println(compact(JsonAST.render(json)))
>
>     val map = Map("fname" -> "Alvin", "lname" -> "Alexander")
>     println(compact(JsonAST.render(map)))
> }
> ```
>
> That program prints the following output:
>
> ```
> [1,2,3]
> {"fname":"Alvin","lname":"Alexander"}
> ```

If needed also have a look on [this one](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-json-string-scala-collections-classes/) for creating a JSON String from Scala classes that have collections.

Comment: I tried running this code from a Databricks notebook with Scala 2.12 and the following Maven library coordinates installed on the cluster net.liftweb:lift-json_2.12:3.4.3, but I keep getting syntax errors. Any ideas on steps to get this to run in Databricks? Thanks